# Как напрямую получить ключи и значения массива?

Tags: php

Имеется массив вида "ключ=>значение" и нужно получить его и ключи и значения по отдельности.
Нет смысл городить конструкции с перебором, поиском и другими доп. вычислениями - они используются только один раз, но в разных местах.

Делаю так, но не ни ключи ни значения не получаю.
ЧЯДНТ? Как надо?

```
<?php echo "<i></i><span>".array_keys($arrrel[0])." <strong>".array_values($arrrel[0]). "</strong></span>"; ?>
...
<?php echo "<i></i><span>".array_keys($arrrel[1])." <strong>".array_values($arrrel[1]). "</strong></span>"; ?>
..
```

Comment: что там у вас в `$arrrel`, и что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: @teran в $arrrel массив типа `("яблоко"=>"красное", "лимон"=>"кислый")`. Надо вывести и ключи и значения в разных местах.

Comment: Ну и что ты тогда хочешь получить из $arrrel[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сделали в примере почти правильно.

Вот вариант с необходимым синтаксисом:

```php
$arrrel = array("яблоко"=>"красное", "лимон"=>"кислый");

echo "<i></i><span>".array_keys($arrrel)[0]." <strong>".array_values($arrrel)[0]. "</strong></span>";
echo "<i></i><span>".array_keys($arrrel)[1]." <strong>".array_values($arrrel)[1]. "</strong></span>";
```

Comment: Спасибо. Извини раньше не мог ответить - был забанен из-за барана в короне.